# Dog.java:16: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value

Tags: java, oop

Can't figure it out...

```
class Dog {
  int age;
  public Dog(int dogsAge) {
    age = dogsAge;
  }

  public void bark() {
    System.out.println("Woof!");
  }

  public void run(int feet) {
    System.out.println("Your dog ran " + feet + " feet!");
  }

  public void getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog spike = new Dog(999);
    spike.bark();
    spike.run(999);
  }

}
```

I think the error is in the part **return age;**.

And sorry if i'm not descriptive enough, I am new to Java.

Comment: Please always include the full error traceback in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the variable `age` is `int` that returned type should be `int` instead of `void`.

```
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

`void` means that no value is returned to caller side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method like this

```
 public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
```

This is a getter method for `age`. age is of type `int` in your program,so instead of `void`,return int and you will be good.`void` indicates that this method is not going to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can't return a value if the method is void. change your getAge method to return an int.

```
  public int getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }
```